# Get last one version of SPFileVersion

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-services, sharepoint-online

I'm trying to implement a method  that retrieve a "*file version"*  that will must be the same of the  parameter number I'm going o pass.

```
SPListItem item = attachments.First();

                                                 var ultimaVersione = (from SPListItemVersion ver in item.Versions where ver.IsCurrentVersion select ver).First();                         

                                                 var tutteLeVersioni = item.File.Versions;

                                                 var versioni = new int[tutteLeVersioni.Count];
                                                 for (int i = 0; i <= versioni.Length; i++ )
                                                 {  
                                                     if(tutteLeVersioni[i].ID== getFileObj.versionNumber)
                                                     {
                                                         tutteLeVersioni.RestoreByID(tutteLeVersioni[i].ID);
                                                         files.Add(new fileList() { file = tutteLeVersioni[i].File.OpenBinary() });
                                                         tutteLeVersioni.RestoreByID(ultimaVersione.VersionId);
                                                         found = true;
                                                     }
                                                 }
```

I've been trying restoring the file with the chosen version, and then retrieve it. 
But I noticed that with the method "RestoreByID()", it it puts one more version Item inside the Item. 
Some idea???

Comment: Please clarify the question.  Is it to find out how to obtain the particular copy of the version through code?  Is it the code to Restore the version?  Is it something else?  Also, I'd recommend doing a file restore through the SharePoint User Interface to see the experience you get, then that may help in translating to what you are seeing in code.

Comment: Hi Brian.I 'm trying to obtain a particular copy of file of a specific version, through code

Comment: Please edit the question to clarify this.  For example: "My question is, using the Server Side SharePoint API, how can I retrieve a file version given the version's history id?"

Comment: Ciao. Sto implementando un metodo che mi consenta di recuperare la copia del file che ha un  specifico ID version. Se chiamo la proprietà "file" di SPFileVersion, mi ritorna sempre il "parent file object", cioè il contenuto del file è sempre quello più aggiornato. Vorrei poter recuperare il contenuto del file della versione specificata.